# Page disallow in robots.txt but indexed by Google. How it is possible?

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

My website faces coverage issues in Google Search Console. Check the following message by Google in GSC:

> Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt

I disallow my account page (`https://www.joujou.com.au/account/`) in robots.txt but it is indexed by Google. Is it possible for a page to index in Google if that page is already disallowed in the robots.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt just prevents Googlebot from seeing the contents of the page. However, if someone links to your page, even if Google doesn't see the contents, Google knows there's a webpage at that destination URL.

If enough people link to the page, Google may decide to add it and surface it in the index. Many times Google will gather context of that webpage from the content that links to it and the anchor text of the links.

If you truly don't want a URL to be in the Google index, there are 2 advised approaches.

1. Add a [robots meta tag](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag) to the page with a NOINDEX command. **note:** You'll have to allow Google to crawl the URL for it to see the NOINDEX command. So you'll have to undo the disallow command in your robots.txt file
2. Add HTTP Basic Authentication to the page

Either approaches will ensure Google does not add the URL to the index. However, Google will still crawl the URL from time to time.

For more context, Google representative [John Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230004/john-mueller) recently said this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1147128244954697728).

> ... robots.txt will definitely block crawling of the content (if
>   disallowed), though not necessarily indexing of the URLs. [however,] without
>   content, it's hard to rank